# kontextbezogenes Problem

Tags: verb

Neulich las ich ein Gedicht von Andreas Kley und stieß dabei auf eine merkwürdige Zeile:

> Ärzte. Sie kommen und retten dein Leben.
>
> **Oft bleibt nicht mehr als ein Windhauch an Zeit.**
>
> Oft aber geht all ihr Retten daneben.
>
> Dann bist du sicher dem Tode geweiht.

Was bedeutet der fettgedruckte Teil? Wie soll ich das interpretieren? Warum ist es eigentlich **an** Zeit?

Comment: Bei 'Zeit' denke ich eher an einen 'Wimpernschlag', der ist wirklich schnell vorbei, passt aber nicht ins Metrum. Ein 'Windhauch' ist nicht in erster Linie kurz, sondern schwach. Eine 'schwache Zeit'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Der Windhauch ist das Maß, in dem die Zeit gemessen wird.

Dieses *an* wird meist weggelassen, wenn ohnehin klar ist, dass es sich um ein Maß handelt. Oft wird es auch durch *von* ersetzt.

> ein Glas Wasser
>
> ein Glas an/von Wasser *(unüblich)*
>
> eine Menge Arbeit
>
> eine Menge an/von Arbeit

Answer (score 3):

> ein Windhauch an Zeit

würde ich mit

> ein kleines bisschen Zeit

übersetzen, da ein Windhauch ein kleines bisschen Wind ist.

Als Zeiteinheit ist »Windhauch« untauglich, denn wenn ich frage

> Wie lange hat das gedauert?

kann sich unter der Antwort

> 25 Windhauche

niemand etwas vorstellen.

Die Frage nach dem »an« wurde bereits erschöpfend behandelt.

Answer (score 1):

*»Zeit«* ist eine Größe, die gemessen wird, *»Windhauch«* ist eine Maßeinheit die geeignet ist, diese Größe zu messen, (zumindest im sprachlichen Sinn, eine konkrete Definition dieser Einheit ist nicht erforderlich, es ist wohl die zeitliche Dauer eines durchschnittlichen Windhauchs gemeint), und *»ein«* ist die Anzahl der "gemessenen" Einheiten.

Damit ist

> ein Windhauch an Zeit

nichts weiter als eine konkrete Ausprägung des Musters

> <*Anzahl*> <*Einheit*> an <*Größe*>

Andere Beispiele:

- Wir kitzeln **das letzte Quäntchen an Geschwindigkeit** bei der Dateneingabe heraus. *(Aus einer Werbebroschüre)*
- **Ein Meer an Zeit** *(Buchtitel)*

Die Verwendung der Präposition *»an«* ist aber selten, und in der Alltagssprache nicht gebräuchlich. Man findet das oben beschriebene Muster nur in literarischen Texten und in Texten, die an Literatur erinnern wollen (wie z.B. in den beiden zitierten Beispielen).

Das Standardmuster für Maßangaben kommt ohne Präposition aus:

> vier Meter Leinen
>   drei Teelöffel Hefe
>   eine Packung Kaugummi